# Having a VBA Checkbox add a value to a cell on a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I've managed to scrounge up a few bits of code to add in a checkbox on Excel, which works fine, but I want to have my calculations on a second sheet that I can hide. I need two checkboxes which are mutually exclusive, only one can be checked at a time, or both left unchecked. When either box is ticked, I need them to put a value in a cell on Sheet 2.

So far I have this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("F22").Value = -1190
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then Range("F22").Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then Range("G22").Value = 1190
1190
If CheckBox2.Value = False Then Range("G22").Value = 0
End Sub
```

I obviously need the change the "F22" and "G22" to be the respective cells on the second sheet, but I've tried adding "Sheet2!" in a variety of ways with no success.

(Everything else is working fine, I just don't want to have those cells on the same sheet, so I can keep them locked away.)

Comment: Try using Sheets(“Sheet2”).Range(“G22”) or Sheets(2).Range(“G22”)

Comment: You can use `Worksheets()`. Examples: https://wellsr.com/vba/excel/worksheet-object/

Comment: Thanks guys, got it working with Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F22")